# Using flutter, how do you do role-based authentication?

Tags: dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I have an app in which the users are sorted into roles, role a and role b, and based on your role, you will see a different UI. How do I get the users role using firebase authentication, because I have only seen the features which allow the users to sign in, but not with roles?

Comment: If Single user have two different roles then you should give role selection screen, otherwise you can using multiple ways

Comment: When the user signs up, a role will be assigned to them. Every user has only one role and no user can have two roles.

Comment: See: https://github.com/casbin/casbin-dart

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out that I can't do role-based authentication using firebase authentication alone. I need to use firestore in order to store what role the user is. You cannot store roles in firebase authentication, but can only use firebase authentication to log in users.

Comment: I have the similar requirement too. i will roles in response message of login request. based on that i need to enable/disable features. what's the best way to do this in flutter?